# Determine a view in a specific view in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have two table views: table-A and table-B.

In each table view there are buttons in a grid manner in their respective cell of each table view. I need to determine whether the button which I have pressed belongs to table-A or table-B. If it is possible, how could I achieve this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `tag` on the button. Or look at the superview of the button. Or associate another object with the button (`objc_setAssociatedObject`). There are many possibilities.

Comment: I think tag option is the best.

Comment: @suraj, using a category with `objc_setAssociatedObject` to allow the button to have a properly named and typed property is probably the most correct solution. Tags are rather limited.